# Unexpected Results When Comparing getString() Return Values

Tags: java

I am facing a problem is that the if statement which I am coding is producing wrong results and can't compare two results:

My code is:

`temp_code` has value `130` and `rs.getString(employee_id)` has value `130` also

```
String temp_code = rs.getString(employee_id);

if ((rs.getString(employee_id)).equals(temp_code)) 
{
out.println("employee IDs equal");
}
else
{
out.println("employee IDs not equal");
}
```

But it is giving me that the employee IDs not equal

when I am printing the values both of them are 130 and when I am printing the value of the:

```
out.println((rs.getString(employee_id)).equals(temp_code));
```

It is producing false value

Comment: Is that your actual code? If it is, why are you calling `getString()` with the same `employee_id` twice in a row? If it's not, can you please show us your actual code?

Comment: What type is the `rs` variable? Custom class or something else?

Comment: I am comparing them to print the Group name, suppose you want to display each employee records group by name. The name and below it the records

Comment: I see no code above that actually prints the value of what you are comparing. Are you SURE they are equal? If you are sure about that, well, then I say that apparently they are not.

Comment: @user1080320 Right, but my point is you're not actually retrieving the employee id twice in a row and comparing; you're storing an earlier employee id in `temp_code` and then comparing that as you go through the `ResultSet` (or at least that's what would make sense.) Given that, please post code that more closely resembles what you actually have, since the current code doesn't really help us help you.

Answer (score 3):

One of the strings probably has a whitespace character in it.  Print them out bracketed by other characters, eg:

```
out.println("[" + rs.getString(employee_id) + "]);
out.println("[" + temp_code + "]);
```

Comment: Well, maybe.  You see, it depends on your requirements.  If it matters to you - if it counts as "different" for your purposes that they have whitespace differences, then don't trim them.  But if it doesn't count - sure, trim them.  And in fact if they're really supposed to be integers, trim them and get the int value; ints are easier to compare than strings.